# Why does between? work differently for Date and DateTime in ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, date, datetime

The [doc](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveSupport/TimeWithZone/between%3F) says:

> between?(min, max) public
>
> Returns true if the current object’s time is within the specified min
>   and max time.

In Ruby:

```
>> DateTime.now.between?(DateTime.now, DateTime.now+1)
=> false
>> Date.today.between?(Date.today, Date.today+1)
=> true
```

By using `.current` in Rails the discrepancy becomes even clearer, since you'd especially assume this method would have similar behavior on `DateTime` and `Date`:

```
>> DateTime.current.between?(DateTime.current, DateTime.current+1)
=> false
>> Date.current.between?(Date.current, Date.current+1)
=> true
```

Is this intentional behavior? If so, why? It seems fairly odd that the behavior when dealing with the `min` edge of the interval is not idiosyncratic. Especially when considering that the `max` part is idiosyncratic:

```
>> DateTime.now.between?(DateTime.now-1, DateTime.now)
=> true
>> Date.today.between?(Date.today-1, Date.today)
=> true
```

Comment: `DateTime.now != DateTime.now`, but `Date.today == Date.today`, unless you manage to hit the exact moment the day changes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Lets launch irb and run those code:

```
"#{DateTime.now.inspect} \n #{DateTime.now.inspect}"
```

Result'll be something like this:

```
#<DateTime: 2017-03-22T11:42:28+03:00 ((2457835j,31348s,373353553n),+10800s,2299161j)>
#<DateTime: 2017-03-22T11:42:28+03:00 ((2457835j,31348s,373449152n),+10800s,2299161j)>
```

As you can see, there is difference in nanoseconds (373353553n < 373449152n)

**Lets imagine that difference is equal to 'x', and DateTime.now is equal to 'Now', then:**

> 1) DateTime.now.between?(DateTime.now, DateTime.now+1.second)
>
> Now.between?(Now+x, Now+x+x+1.second) => false
>
> 2) DateTime.now.between?(DateTime.now-1, DateTime.now)
>
> Now.between?(Now+x-1.second, Now+x+x) => true

Comment: Thanks, this also explains why the max part always returns true, which was still a conundrum after reading the other answers.

Answer (score 2):

That is because times goes by.
Your first DateTime.now, which you check against, is a couple of milliseconds before your second DateTime.now, in brackets.

Answer (score 2):

As others have mentioned :

```
a.between?(b,c)
```

`a` is interpreted a few milliseconds before `b` and `c`.

The shortest way to get the desired result would be :

```
(now=DateTime.now).between?(now, now+1)
#=> true
```

You could also reverse the order in which the `DateTime` objects are initialized :

```
(DateTime.now..DateTime.now+1).cover? DateTime.now
#=> true
```

Answer (score 1):

Well it seems like its issue of few milliseconds

```
DateTime.now.between?(DateTime.now, DateTime.now+1)
^ executing first     ^ executing after few milliseconds or nanoseconds
```

The value of `DateTime` with what you are comparing is old than the DateTime`value in`between?`

But if you save it in variable

```
now = DateTime.now
now.between?(now,now+1)
#=> true
```

Also, as @ndn commented

```
DateTime.now ==  DateTime.now
#=> false
```